# How to fill Local collection from SQL and go over with For LOOP?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I want to create a **local collection with values I get from a select statement** and then go over them with a `FOR` Loop.

**I can't define the TYPE outside of the PL/SQL Block** because I am not supposed to modify the Database I am querying. I saw several other threads here in SO suggesting to create a Type outside the PL SQL Block.

I want to use the Index to go over the items, because I need to do something special with the last one, I need to differentiate it from the rest.

Here a simplified version of my latest attempt:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE itemsTYPE IS TABLE OF MY_TABLE.ITEM%TYPE;
     items  itemsTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT ITEM INTO items
    From MY_TABLE;

    FOR currentIndex IN 1..items.Count
    LOOP

        IF currentIndex = items.Count THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('END');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(items(currentIndex));
        END IF;

    END LOOP;             

END;
```

In this attempt I get the following error:

> PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

I understand this error, but I don't know how to change my code so it works.

Before I tried different things and I got all kind of errors, I can't seem to find the right way to achieve what I need. Is it even possible?

Comment: Your problem is you are using `into` clause. When work with collections you must use `bulk collect into` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE itemsTYPE IS TABLE OF MY_TABLE.ITEM%TYPE;
     items  itemsTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT ITEM BULK COLLECT INTO items
    From MY_TABLE;

    FOR currentIndex IN 1..items.Count
    LOOP

        IF currentIndex = items.Count THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('END');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(items(currentIndex));
        END IF;

    END LOOP;             

END;
```